# not able to find or load main class Files

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, mainclass

I'm trying to build a simple jdbc database call application. I have the jars in the buildpath and and my sqljdbc_Auth.dll is in the folder:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\jdbc\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64

I'm getting this error message

> Error: Could not find or load main class Files

my VM arguments: looks like this...

> -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\jdbc\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64

And that's what I know so far. Is loading the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the `java.library.path` more involved than that?

Comment: If I could get the information I needed from other's questions I wouldn't ask my own.

Comment: Where does the class file that contains `main()` reside?

Comment: the class file is in workspace/projectName/src/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are using Eclipse. This:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\jdbc\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64
```

will be parsed as multiple arguments, because it has spaces in. I'm not very familiar with Windows, but you probably need to replace it with something like this:

```
"-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\jdbc\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64"
```

Comment: oh you know what it was? x86 instead :P Thank you!

Comment: Or just install java/other tool in some separate directory on disk having no spaces in folder names i.e. `C:\Work\Java`